# Page info sometimes fetched after debugging

Tags: facebook, debugging

This is very weird.
I have a page with multiple blogs (home made, no wordpress).
It happens "sometimes" that when I try to share a blog post, the facebook window seems to fail in fetching data from my blog. So what happens is that No pictures or description or title shows in the facebook window. This maybe happens 1 times every 20 posts. Weird huh?

The og tags look good. I have compared the og tags for the working posts with the failing ones. I can NOT see any difference. I mean something special with the data in the og tags.

Most weird is that I then try to look at the debugger. I go here:
http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug

I then paste the url of the post that fails to fetch information. Well, after I have done this step, I go back to the post, and when I click on the share button, the data is fetched correctly!!!
Somebody that have experienced the same issue?

Comment: Sounds like an issue with your site, where some of the content isn't returned when FB requests it. Visiting the debugger forces a refresh of the FB cache, so that is normal. You'll need to give more details about your site to diagnose this.

Comment: Ok, I see. Well, my site is using memcache (it is a php application). However, the blog posts that have the share function, they use to have things like:user_id, post_id.
Example:On a page for a blogger, there are lets say 6 posts. For each post there is the facebook share button. The link is:
http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.mysite.com%2FuserBlog%2Fentry.php%3Fuid%3D463%26beid%3D2329813
When the popup shows up, the url in the window is:
http://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.mysite.com%2FuserBlog%2Fentry.php%3Fuid%3D463%26beid%3D2329813

Comment: The page itself where the share button appears is:
http%3A%2F%2Fwww.mysite.com%2FuserBlog%2F%3Fuid%3D463%26beid%3D2329813
Those time when facebook fails getting details about the page, I try to browse the page with my browser. Response is 200. I also tried to have a look at the page source. The og tags looks ok. The generated html too. What would you suggest I can do for simulating the requests sent from facebook that fail? Thanks a lot.

Comment: I have now tried to test adding timstamp in the url. So I added something like:
%26t%3D1357807047
at the end of the previous written url.
Unfortunately this doesnt change the result.
I thought that the cache/memcache on my server could be the problem. But I guess this test shows that the problemn is not the cache.

Comment: PS: The webapp is running on 3 front end servers. If this may be good to know.

Comment: More details (sigh):

I copied the html generetad by the php page where the facebook sharer fails. I cpied all the genretad html content and pastes it into a file named something like test.php. On that file I changed the og:url to point to test.php.
Well, when trying to share, all the information is fetched correctly by facebook :(

Comment: It sounds like you've got some stuff to untangle. While you're ripping into your setup, the `sharer.php` endpoint is deprecated. You should migrate to the like button.

Comment: But does the LIKE functionality offer the same as Share? Sorry, Im not so familiari with fb. But with share, a popup appears where you can decide where to put the story (in the timeline, in a group etc), You can also write something if you like, before posting. The LIKE doesnt seem to give flexibility to do anything ather than "liking" a page.

Comment: If you want the user to comment, you need to implement the [Feed Dialog](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/feed/) The [Like plugin](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/) is simpler to implement though.

Comment: I understand. When I click on a sharer.php (that is deprecated) I see at the top "Share this link".
In Feed Dialog I see "Upload to your log".
Also I see some other difference. WIth sharer you can upload the story to many places, timeline, friend wall etc. With the new one ou only post it to your own log.
More over, the feed dialog isn't using the go tags?!?
The old sharer used to show thumbnails for all the images on the page you going to share.

Comment: The feed dialog seems only to show the picture you send as parameter.
Isn't there any other link that provides the same functionality?
Or is it possible to customise feed dialog to make it look the old sharer.php?